# How to place jsp views in a Maven Archetype?

Tags: java, maven, web-applications

I am creating a maven archetype and want JSP views in WEB-INF folder of the maven project that will be created using the maven archetype.

WEB-INF folder is not present in maven archetype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the folder and the file to the archetype project and build the archetype.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I know its a silly question but i am new to Maven.